# How to redirect dd to pv?

Tags: pipe, dd, pv

This is my dd command which I need to modify:

```
dd if=/tmp/nfs/image.dd of=/dev/sda bs=16k
```

Now I would like to use `pv` to limit the speed of copying from NFS server. How can I achieve that? I know that `--rate-limit` does the job, but I am not sure how to construct pipes.

Comment: Have you looked at the [man page for `pv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)? The options are all listed there.

Comment: Actually I am not sure how to use pipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you *must* read the block device using a block size of 16K:

```
dd if=/mnt/nfs bs=16k | pv -L <rate> > /dev/sda
```

Where `<rate>` is the maximum allowed amount of bytes per second to be transferred, or the maximum allowed amount of kibibytes, mibibytes, gibibytes, [...] per second to be transferred if K, M, G, [...] is specified.

However if you don't really have to read the file using a block size of 16K, just use `pv`, which can read block devices:

```
pv -L <rate> /mnt/nfs > /dev/sda
```

Comment: The question has `/dev/sda` as the output, not the input.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, that was indeed dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `dd` here. `pv` already does the job of shoveling its input to its output.

```
pv -L 1m </tmp/nfs >/dev/sda
```

Despite what you may have read on some web pages, there is no magic in `dd`. You don't need to use it to access devices. All the magic is in the `/dev/stuff`.

Note: this command makes sense if `/tmp/nfs` is a disk image and you want to write it onto the disk `/dev/sda`. It is equivalent to the command in your question apart from the rate limiting. No NFS server appears to be involved.

Comment: yes, in `/tmp/nfs` I just missed the image file name. I will give it a try.